# Was Opportunity's last message to Earth "My battery is low and it's getting dark"?

Tags: space-flight, nasa, engineering, robotics, mars

On February 13 2019, NASA announced that [Opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)) - a Mars rover launched in 2003 with an intended longevity of three months - [was likely to be dead](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/feb/13/nasa-makes-final-attempt-to-communicate-with-mars-rover-opportunity).

In the wake of this event, and the outpouring of emotion it triggered, I've seen the following claim widely disseminated on social media:

[image: Image of Opportunity overlaid with the caption: "Opportunity's last message to Earth - 'My battery is low and it's getting dark'"]

- Source: [Facebook page of author Morgan S Hazelwood](https://www.facebook.com/MorganSHazelwood/posts/2220504991537456)

Source of similar claims:

- [ABC7News](https://abc7news.com/5137455/?ex_cid=TA_KGO_FB)
- [India Today](https://www.facebook.com/IndiaToday/posts/10157846947977119)

This [blog article](https://ascienceenthusiast.com/mars-opportunity-rover-officially-dead/?fbclid=IwAR2ZQGbOyJk9_6JIlacomoT9MnVx12NVVpgque-ZH0Xxp2y8nzyt8JlNB4U):

> Last June as the dust storm descended upon Opportunity, the rover’s last message essentially said “my battery is low, and it’s getting very dark.”

This echoes the tweet from [Jacob Margolis](https://twitter.com/JacobMargolis/status/1095436913173880832) quoted in the 7ABC News and India today articles:

> The last message they received was basically, “My battery is low and it’s getting dark.”

Is Opportunity actually capable of such advanced communication skills? Is this someone simply trying to anthropomorphise Opportunity's last contact with the Earth?

Comment: This is the oldest source I can find: https://twitter.com/JacobMargolis/status/1095436913173880832

Comment: Folks, we all realize this can't be _literally_ true, but this is not the place to attempt an answer based on this (or pass judgement on the question). Be kind.

Comment: I've edited the question to accept that it isn't literally true that the message was sent in English form, but it remains a claim that the last message conveyed essentially that info.

Comment: @Oddthinking I've reverted most of that edit because that's not the question I asked, and it's not the one that two users have answered. I understood on a personal level that Mars rovers are not advanced enough to speak in English, but I asked the question I did because that is the most prevailing idea among the general public, as indicated by the image I included, and that's the perspective it will be approached from by someone with little to no knowledge of the field. It makes no sense to dictate the question based on the answer.

Comment: TL;DR: I wrote the question intentionally "naive" and from a standpoint of knowing nothing at all, as that's likely to be the stance of the average member of the general public searching for this information, and that's how you debunk myths.

Comment: This claim isn't notable. Please edit it to show that anyone believes the super-naive interpretation of the claim you have misleadingly adopted, rather than the manner in which is was clearly intended.

Comment: I don't know how much more evidence I can give you of that claim aside from the included image. It says "Opportunity's last *message* to Earth", implying a literal message, and then surrounds that "message" with quotes. Any objective observer can see that the image is claiming the quote is literal. If you're asking for evidence of how widespread that belief is, I'm not sure *what* evidence I can give you of that, other than send you links to the many, many places on social media that I've seen the sentiment spread in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Here at Skeptics.SE we tackle notable claims - claims that many people believe. It is clear that many people believe that the last message from the Opportunity rover was a status message that indicated the battery and light levels. It is not clear that anyone at all misunderstood the word "essentially" and believed that the rover spoke English.

Comment: The word "essentially" has nothing to do with the claim because it's from the article, not the image. The article was included because it was the only potential source for the claim I could personally find - nothing more.

Comment: @Oddthinking No, what's clear is that many people on Skeptics.SE intuitively know that the last message from Opportunity was likely to be a series of digital signals. However, the audience for questions like this isn't the users of this site - it's people in the public domain where the image above came from, and those people don't intuitively know such things. I asked this question so I could have something to point those people to and debunk the myth that Curiosity sends messages in English, which is certainly the case in the larger world outside of SE, and the image is the evidence of that.

Comment: It's easy to find scores of news outlets that present the "My battery is low" quote as if this was the literal transmission, thus making this claim easily notable. I came across [an article](https://www.computerbild.de/artikel/cb-News-Panorama-NASA-Roboter-Opportunity-Mars-Ende-22988687.html) on *Computer Bild* (one of "Europe's best selling computer magazines" according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Bild)) this morning that reported as if the rover really transmitted that messages in plain text. @Hashim: just add a few sites like this, and you should be fine.

Comment: @Schmuddi If I was asked for such, I could have included plenty of links to social media posts containing similar evidence, but I wasn't, so I was still entirely unsure what the problem here was. Is the problem that this site doesn't consider claims on social media as "notable" enough? If so, that's patent idiocy, as anyone keeping up with current affairs should be aware social media is where the vast majority of the modern world consumes the vast majority of its information, and is where the vast majority of modern disinformation (*fake news*, if you like) originates and thrives.

Comment: @Oddthinking "Please edit it to show that anyone believes the super-naive interpretation of the claim..." I don't think it's out of the realm of possibilities that the creators of the Mars rover could have built-in an Easter egg like this and could have activated it now. They went as far as sending poems to Opportunity (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34180/what-was-the-last-message-to-opportunity-today-13-feb-19), so they may as well have included a mechanism to return something like this. I think it's highly unlikely Opportunity sent such a message literally, but it may have.

Comment: @Hashim: 'The word "essentially" has nothing to do with the claim because it's from the article, not the image.' You make a good point there; I concede that.

Comment: @Sklivvz It readily could be literally true. I suspect most users of a site like this correctly assume it was not literally true, but many members of the public will not know that.

Comment: Question is now also on Space.SE (cross reference to here): https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34243/what-was-the-last-message-opportunity-sent

Comment: Source may be here:https://www.patreon.com/posts/24681797

Comment: If it helps, when I saw the meme, I had to do my own research to see that Opportunity didn't actually speak this verbatim.  Remember, this is the craft that sang happy birthday to itself using its servo motors.  This would not be the first time we had Opportunity do something markedly humanlike, for no reason other than to do so.

Comment: @CortAmmon: A more interesting question would be whether the mission was a routine status report, or if logic was triggered to send a "final" status report in the event that worsening conditions made it likely the communications would be lost forever.

Comment: @PedroLobito That Patreon post was from the day after Margolis's tweet, so it appears to be just another artwork inspired (indirectly) by his choice of words.

Comment: @IMSoP I didn't realize that, thank you.

Comment: That could have been true. Nasa needs public support and some engineer could have programmed "My battery is low and it's getting dark" as a last message instead of a more technical/efficient message.

Comment: @Sklivvz - actually, it CAN be literally true, and I'd think nothing of it. Now, if the message was meant in a idiomatic, metaphorical, poetic way instead of a literal reporting of energy levels and visibility conditions, that would be less believable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Other answers give good technical answers to what the last message would actually have looked like, but I thought it worth tackling the angle of where the quote came from.

Wikipedia cites [an article on LAist](https://laist.com/2019/02/16/jpl_mars_rover_opportunity_battery_is_low_and_its_getting_dark.php) a Los Angeles local news / blogging site, written by Jacob Margolis.

In it he describes how he coined the phrase:

> "My battery is low and it's getting dark."
>
> That's how I felt when I heard that NASA's Opportunity rover mission was coming to an end after 15 years. That Oppy, the rover, was officially dead, and that it had sent back one last alarming communication to Earth before finding its final resting place in Perseverance Valley on the surface of Mars.

On the evening of Feb 12, 2019, he posted a thread of 11 tweets on Twitter, describing the situation, and including various photos from the rover. [Tweet number 3](https://twitter.com/JacobMargolis/status/1095436913173880832) in that thread reads:

> The last message they received was basically, "My battery is low and it's getting dark." They hoped that the windy season would clear dust off the solar panels (if that was the problem). Since then they've been pinging her again and again, every way they knew… 3/

This received numerous responses on Twitter, and as it spread, the context was naturally lost. As Margolis continues:

> People started talking about it as if they were actually the exact last words that the rover said. The [NY Daily News](https://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/ny-news-martian-rover-final-message-20190215-story.html) reported it as fact.
>
> JPL contacted me to let me know that they were being inundated with questions about the final message. And while it seemed like most people understood the context within the tweet, many didn't.

In response to queries about whether these really were "the last words", he says:

> As NPR's Scott Simon said, it's a "[poetic translation](https://www.npr.org/2019/02/16/695293679/opinion-good-night-oppy-a-farewell-to-nasas-mars-rover?utm_campaign=storyshare&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_medium=social)."

He then quotes Deputy Project Scientist Abigail Fraeman:

> And then it was Sunday, we actually got a communication from the rover and we were shocked. It basically said we had no power left, and that was the last time we heard from it.

...and John Callas, the project manager:

> It also told us the skies were incredibly dark, to the point where no sunlight gets through. It's night time during the day.

In both cases, the "it" seems to refer to the rover, anthropomorphising it; this appears to have been Margolis's inspiration to rephrase the message as a quote in the first person.

Comment: Best answer here

Comment: So the status report was more than a "My battery charge level is XX and solar input is YY", but was instead a "There will likely be no chance to send a message later, so send one now to let people know what happened"?:  If so, the anthropomorphized version is in some ways less emotional than the reality (since "my battery happens to be low, and it happens to be dark" wouldn't normally have any fatalistic implications, unlike e.g. "Energy generation persistently ineffective; improvement not expected; reserves insufficient to allow further transmissions unless situation spontaneously improves."

Comment: @supercat, as far as I can tell, "it's getting dark" is the final science transmission: an atmospheric-opacity photograph of the Sun -- or where the Sun would be if dust weren't blocking 99.998% of the light.  "My battery is low" is the final engineering-status transmission, which was notification of a low-battery fault.

Comment: Selecting this as best answer for now, possibly temporarily, to ensure it gets as much upvotes as it deserves. This is the only answer that gets to the crux of the the claim itself and its source, while underscoring just how necessary the question was - it's become clear in the subsequent week since the NASA announcement that the question was needed, but on the 14th February it was far less clear to most and was an uphill struggle just to keep it open.

Comment: @supercat Not even "my battery charge level is XX and solar input is YY". The message was "my battery charge level is XX. Here's a picture of the sky" The opacity values were calculated on Earth, the rover didn't analyze them.

Comment: @Rekesoft: I would have expected that the rover would include as part of its status report information about how much current it was getting from the solar panels, to allow for the possibility that abnormally-low power input might be noticed in time to deal with it (e.g. in the unlikely even that some wind-blown debris landed on the panels).

Answer (score 200):

From a [NASA blog post](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/rover-status/opportunity/recent/all/?y=2018#sols-5108) made the day after contact was lost:

> The dust storm that is affecting Opportunity has greatly intensified.
>
> The atmospheric opacity (tau) over the rover has increased to a record 10.8 on Sol 5111 (June 10, 2018). Power levels on the rover have dropped to a record low of ~22 watt hours. As expected, Opportunity has tripped a low-power fault and gone silent. A 72-hour spacecraft emergency was declared on the afternoon of Sol 5111 (June 10, 2018), anticipating the low-power fault.

High atmospheric opacity means that the atmosphere is blocking a lot of sunlight, making it dark. [Future estimates of atmospheric opacity](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/rover-status/opportunity/recent/all/) are far less precise, so we can conclude that the measurement of tau was transmitted from the rover rather than another source.

From an [interview](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jonathanocallaghan/2019/02/18/this-was-the-last-photo-taken-by-nasas-opportunity-rover-on-mars/#3ed18ffe5a9a) given later:

> "We are looking at an incredibly small amount of sunlight – .002 percent of the normal sunlight that we would expect to see," Bill Nelson from NASA’s Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL), chief of the Opportunity mission’s engineering team, told Mashable. "If you were there, it would be late twilight. Your human eye would still be able to make out some features, but it would be very dark."

The darkness and record low battery are consistent with the claim. The last [image](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/all/opportunity.html) sent by opportunity was static and blackness. The filename indicates it was taken at 4:24 PM UTC.

Opportunity definitely transmitted the information in the claim on its last day. I do not know if it transmitted anything else in a separate transmission afterwards. It most certainly did not transmit a plain English message ready to be memed, but rather a technical status update that NASA's bloggers interpreted for us, and then was reinterpreted into the meme.

As a personal note, if I am on my deathbed and I say something meaningful and wise, and then I follow it up with a mundane comment right before I die, please remember the wise thing as my last words.

Comment: The last 3 SOL image sets (5107, 5109, 5111) contain only "static" or black images. _Black spaces typically mean partial data has arrived, but Opportunity will fill in the rest of the data as soon as possible._ The "static" is possibly haze from a dust storm, since we know the opacity was very high.

Comment: Thank you for resisting the temptation to put a simple "yes" or "no" in your answer and instead focusing on the reality of what happened.

Comment: Bob, that is a very good request at the end of your answer.

Comment: .... unless your final words on your deathbed are "Daisy, Daisy..."   Then we're holding you to them!

Answer (score 94):

Opportunity does not literally speak English, so no such message was expressed in those terms. However, Opportunity did communicate the information that it had a low battery and it was dark outside.

The rover's flight software outputs a variety of data formats ([summarized in this paper](https://www-robotics.jpl.nasa.gov/publications/Mark_Maimone/isairas08.pdf)) ranging from "event reports" to telemetry to binary data produced by the spacecraft's subsystems (including imagery from cameras and other research products). The result of all of that is [downlinked to earth](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series13/DeepCommo_Chapter7--141030.pdf) and then processed on the ground by different teams into human-readable output. While there is [a great deal of public data available for download](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mer/index.htm), I don't believe this applies to the raw transmissions from the rover, but you can see [the ACSV format](https://www-robotics.jpl.nasa.gov/publications/Mark_Maimone/isairas08.pdf) some of the engineering data is processed into. Scientists then process and review that data and write things about it in English, anything from technical reports ("a measured tau of 10.8") to the more poetic "my battery is low, and it’s getting very dark."

Here's the [Sol 5110-5114 MER B Downlink Report](http://an.rsl.wustl.edu/su/i5P9Kbf4L7) from mission management conveying information about the last transmissions received from the rover:

> Mission Manager
>
> *** Tau Value is NOT a Typographical Error ***
>
> Overall Assessment
>   Opportunity is currently in the midst of a severe dust storm though all subsystems are still operating as expected in RAM mode as of the Sol 5111 UHF pass. Solar array energy is approximately 22 W-hrs, with a measured tau of 10.8. This Tau measurement is the highest ever recorded from a ground station on the planet Mars. Dust factor was previously estimated at 3.27 as of Sol 5108.
>
> With analysis from the data from the Sol 5111 downlink, we expected the rover to enter a low power fault mode very soon after that point in time. Since then, there have been no beeps nor fault windows detected during DSN coverage periods. This behavior is fully in line with array energy expectations, as Opportunity will use deep sleep during such times. We are now waiting for the skies above Opportunity to clear enough for the solar energy to support the fault communications windows (which will send signals to Earth). The team has suspended nominal sequence operations, and we are listening every day for Opportunity to talk to us via one of the fault windows. Thermal predictions carry a positive medium to long term message, whether it takes several sols or several weeks for the storm to weaken and let the sun through. We expect no thermal damage to the batteries or computer systems, and every sol is one closer to summer warmth. Obviously, the team is concerned. But, all of the data and our knowledge indicate that Opportunity is likely to be doing more geological experiments during the upcoming Martian summer, helping unwrap the mysteries of Endeavour crater. Until then, our current mission phase is one of patience and readiness.
>
> Opportunity did not drive during this period.

[As can be shown in this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)#End_of_mission), 22 W-hrs is a very low value for energy collected from the solar array as compared to previous periods. At this time, the scientists considered "a low power fault" to be "inevitable" (note though that "There is no danger to the spacecraft going into a low power fault. The only danger is the temperature getting too cold and damaging the battery or the instruments.") The tau value (atmospheric opacity) is [the highest ever recorded](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/21917/atmospheric-opacity-from-opportunitys-point-of-view/), so high that the report includes a prominent note alerting readers that it's not a typo. The rover does not calculate this value itself; [it takes a picture of the sun through a solar filter](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2007/1053.html), and scientists process that image on the ground to determine the numerical value. In other words, the spacecraft reported data indicating low energy and darkness.

Opportunity also sent back a final [Pancam image](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/instruments/pancam/) at that time. It's the image that was used to calculate that tau value. It's very dark:
[image: static]

Thanks Oppy!

Comment: How do you know that the image was used to calculate the Tau value?

Comment: @BobTheAverage The pancam has a filter wheel, it switches to the solar IR filter and then looks at the sun. Since that was the final image, it is possible it was not looking at the sun, as the camera needs to be able to see the sun to take a picture of it. It first looks at a sundial to find the sun relative to the rover, it is more probable that final picture was of the sundial. The last posted picture which shows the sun is from 5 days earlier

Comment: @BobTheAverage It looks like that is the image used to calc tau, the prior image of the sun 5 days (5106) earlier showed a tau of 2.115, and continued to climb to an estimated 3.27 on 5108, estimated 6 on 5109, and finally at 10.8 on 5111. That final image from the mission manager docs was literally named "sol5111_pancam_tau.jpg"

Comment: "It's getting dark" is a pretty good summation of that image.  A Tau of 10.8 means that 99.998% of the Sun's light is being blocked by dust.

Comment: @RichieFrame Where are you getting that filename? My link to it, (https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/all/opportunity_p5111_text.html) shows that the filename is a cryptic string of characters. When decoded this string indicates that the pancam was using the solar filter, which is 440 nm, which is blue not IR.

Comment: @BobTheAverage The filename is sol5111_pancam_tau.jpg. That's listed in the [analyst's notebook](https://an.rsl.wustl.edu/merb/merxBrowser/an3.aspx?it=D1&ii=22771) and included as an attachment to the mission manager's report, which describes it as "Sol 5111 Pancam Tau (10.8)" If I've misidentified the image, just let me know.

Comment: @BobTheAverage by IR filter, I mean IR block, which kicks out the red and IR, letting yellow, green, and blue through. Max solar energy output is around 450nm, so having the IR filter be most transparent around that wavelength is optimal (as long as it is not 434nm)

Answer (score 16):

[This Metro article](https://metro.co.uk/2019/02/15/scientist-gets-tattoo-showing-opportunity-rovers-final-reading-mars-8632729/) cites a [tweet](https://twitter.com/PlanetaryKeri/status/1095827820918370305?s=20) by Keri Bean, an engineer who worked on the opportunity mission who had Oppy’s final measurement tattooed on her arm.

> This tattoo means more to me than just Oppy. Of course, the biggest significance is this is Oppy’s final measurement. I studied tau (atmospheric optical depth) as a student researcher. Don’t worry, I consulted my advisor on the value before committing to the ink

As others have said, oppy doesn’t speak plain English, transmissions are simply packets of data, so the final message would most likely be as per the image of the tattoo:

> τ=10.8

[image]
<sup>@PlanetaryKeri</sup>

This could then be interpreted to the message in the meme.

Comment: Aren’t the other answers stating that tau is calculated by mission control, not by Oppy?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm one answer does but I’ve seen no definite source for the claim.

Comment: It's also very unlikely that the transmission included a unicode tau character and an equals sign, or decimal digits. But Descartes never said 'I think therefore I am' either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be funny if they issued a correction and it was actually 10.7?

Comment: @JasonC a very frustrating rounding error!!

Comment: @Notts90 I love your commitment!